# Selenium + Java + Screen Recorder - Not able to record screen

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, video, screen-recording

I have created the next class for Recording video in the Selenium Webriver Automation.

First of all, for this I'm using the Monte Media jar (Dependency in POM):

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.stephenc.monte</groupId>
        <artifactId>monte-screen-recorder</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The class that I have created is the next:

```
public class Video {

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Video.class);
private Properties prop = null;
private String path = "";
private String prefix = "";
private String extension = "";
private String time = "";
private static ScreenRecorder screenRecorder;


public void setUp() throws Exception {

    //Crea una instancia de GraphicsConfiguration para obener la configuración gráfica.
    //de la pantalla.
    GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment//
            .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()//
            .getDefaultScreenDevice()//
            .getDefaultConfiguration();

    //Crea la instancia del grabador de video con la configuración necesaria.
    ScreenRecorder screenRecorder = new ScreenRecorder(gc,
            new Format(MediaTypeKey, FormatKeys.MediaType.FILE, MimeTypeKey, MIME_AVI),
            new Format(MediaTypeKey, FormatKeys.MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
                    CompressorNameKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
                    DepthKey, (int) 24, FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(15),
                    QualityKey, 1.0f,
                    KeyFrameIntervalKey, (int) (15 * 60)),
            new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, "black",
                    FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(30)),
            null);

}

public static void iniciaGrabacion(InternetExplorerDriver driver)throws Exception{

    //Método para comenzar de la grabación.
    screenRecorder.start();

}

public static void finalizaGrabacion(InternetExplorerDriver driver)throws Exception{

    //Método para finalizar de la grabación.
    screenRecorder.stop();
}


private void prepareVariables() {
    try {
        prop = AppConfigUtil.getInstance().getProperties();
    } catch (AppConfigException e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
    path = (String) prop.get("video.path");
    prefix = (String) prop.get("video.prefix");
    extension = (String) prop.get("video.extension");
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    time = "" + localDateTime.getYear() + localDateTime.getMonthValue() + localDateTime.getDayOfMonth() + localDateTime.getHour() + localDateTime.getMinute() + localDateTime.getSecond() + localDateTime.getNano();
}
```

What I want to do is calling the static void methods for begin recording (iniciaGrabacion) and stop recodring (finalizaGrabacion) from any other class, not in the same class that I've posted.

```
public static void iniciaGrabacion(InternetExplorerDriver driver)throws Exception{

    //Método para comenzar de la grabación.
    screenRecorder.start();

}

public static void finalizaGrabacion(InternetExplorerDriver driver)throws Exception{

    //Método para finalizar de la grabación.
    screenRecorder.stop();
```

I run any other class, calling these methods with these lines:

```
Video.iniciaGrabacion((InternetExplorerDriver)driver);
```

For close:

```
Video.finalizaGrabacion((InternetExplorerDriver)driver);
```

But i'm facing the next issues:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at cl.chilito.util.report.Video.iniciaGrabacion(Video.java:63)
at cl.chile.automatizacion.casos.prestamos.PrestamoNuevoK.PrestamoNuevoK(PrestamoNuevoK.java:97)
at cl.chile.automatizacion.casos.prestamos.PrestamoNuevoK.testPrestamoNuevoK(PrestamoNuevoK.java:78)
```

Could anybody help me with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: The focus in this question is about the screen video recording, the NullPointException is just the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void startRecording() throws Exception
    {

    File file = new File("C:\\videos");

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int width = screenSize.width;
    int height = screenSize.height;

    Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(0,0, width, height);


    GraphicsConfiguration gc = GraphicsEnvironment
            .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
            .getDefaultScreenDevice()
            .getDefaultConfiguration();


    screenRecorder = new VideoRecorder(gc, captureSize,
            new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.FILE, MimeTypeKey, MIME_AVI),
            new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
                    CompressorNameKey, ENCODING_AVI_TECHSMITH_SCREEN_CAPTURE,
                    DepthKey, 24, FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(15),
                    QualityKey, 1.0f,
                    KeyFrameIntervalKey, 15 * 60),
            new Format(MediaTypeKey, MediaType.VIDEO, EncodingKey, "black",
                    FrameRateKey, Rational.valueOf(30)),
            null, file, "Video"); //Video puede ser cambiado al nombre que deseen
    screenRecorder.start();
}
```

And the stop method:

```
public static void stopRecording() throws Exception
    {
        screenRecorder.stop();
    }
```

Calling from an external class:

Classname.startRecording();
Classname.stopRecording();

Works fine.